# Why can’t PHP SimpleXML just ignore errors and load file?

Tags: php, simplexml

What’s the point of idea not to load XML file at all when it has some syntax issues? Today I got on problems when loading a file that had incorrect encoding defined. It had `UTF-16` headers, but encoded in `UTF-8`. I would understand that, if it wouldn’t be able to determine the proper encoding, but it throws warning, that the file is `UTF-8` encoded, so it does know what to do... It’s a theoretical question. No need to give any examples or saying what I tried. I know how to load the file. Simply by changing `encoding="UTF-16"` to `encoding="UTF-8"` ... but why is it such a problem? Every syntax character is exactly the same in `UTF-8` and `UTF-16`... C# libraries don’t even care...

Comment: You can suppress the warning by using an @ sign before calling the function. But the warning gets thrown for a reason, it's something you should fix.

Comment: There ***is*** a difference between `UTF-8` and `UTF-16`, but just not on the face of it. They're different byte sizes, it's right to argue with an error if it's mis-matching. It's like a browser rendering a web page with invalid HTML, but takes a best-guess to render it properly.

Comment: Suppressing warning doesn't force to load a file. It still returns false. I do understand that there is a difference. But UTF-16 characters can't appear in syntax of XML. It still should be valid. And you can't simply tell it that you don't care... it won't parse it.

Comment: XML is not HTML. XML is expected to be valid. Writing XML parsing tools that can manipulate arbitrary tag-soup and happily drop random data in the process is a pointless and time consuming task.

Comment: "UTF-16 characters can't appear in syntax of XML" - this is false; **every** character in UTF-16 is encoded in (at least) 16 bits. So `<` (the very first char of any valid XML file) is encoded differently in UTF-16 and UTF-8.

Answer (score 5):

As I recall from discussions around the time of XML's design, this zero-tolerance approach is a philosophical response to HTML by the designers of XML. On seeing the incredibly baroque error recovery that had emerged in response to the enormous volume of broken HTML, XML's designers decided to mandate than *any* errors would be fatal.

This is, of course, inconvenient to content authors, who must ensure their documents are exactly well formed, and where necessary, valid too. But by doing so, they allowed XML library authors to concentrate on implementing only XML as specified, rather than accommodating broken XML, no matter how small the breaks. Overall, I think this was a very smart move, resulting in a focus on lean, fast libraries rather than bloated, accommodating ones.

Comment: Furthermore, XML is used to exchange data between computer programs. Booking a hotel room and getting your contact data lost without anyone being warned because some unclosed tag is hardly an acceptable scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your complaint comes from the assumption that encoding information is actually redundant and there's a reliable way to detect the encoding of any given text. That's wrong.

Any piece of software that does encoding detection (typically, a good text editor can do it when loading files) is basically guessing. This is acceptable when:

- There's no other way to do it
- No serious harm can be done
- A person will review the result

Automated XML processing doesn't meet any of these requierements.

You basically ask for data loss as a feature. XML has been explicitly designed against that.

*<sub>(And you've possibly found a bug in your C# libraries, if you're using them correctly.)</sub>*